# Inequality with powers

Tags: calculus, inequality

I would like to prove that for $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$:

$a^{1-p}*b^p+(1-a)^{1-p} (1-b)^p<1~~~if~~~0<p<1$

and

$a^{1-p}*b^p+(1-a)^{1-p} (1-b)^p>1~~~if~~~p>1$

Any help is welcome.

I was trying to approach the problem from different angles:

1. I tried to assume that $a>b$ and increase the formula for $p<1$, by changing b to a in the first summand and a to b in the seconnd, getting:

$a^{1-p}*a^p+(1-b)^{1-p} (1-b)^p=a+1-b>1$, which is, evidentelly, not the result I would like to obtain.

2. I tried to make a very similar trick with moving $a^{1-p}*b^p$ out and substituting a with b, assuming that a>b:

$a^{1-p}*b^p(1+(1-1/a)^{1-p} (1-1/b)^p)<a^{1-p}*b^p(1+(1/b-1)^{1-p} (1/b-1)^p)=a^{1-p}*b^p(1+(-1+1/b))=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1-p}>1$ - overapproximation, evidently.

Comment: Please show your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I made very stupid mistakes.

Let
$$f(p) = a^{1-p}b^p+(1-a)^{1-p}(1-b)^p$$
$$f'(p)=a \ln(b/a) (b/a)^p + (1-a) \ln[(1-b)/(1-a)] [(1-b)/(1-a)]^{p}$$
$$f''(p) = a \ln^2(b/a) (b/a)^p + (1-a) \ln^2[(1-b)/(1-a)] [(1-b)/(1-a)]^{p} > 0$$
and
$$f(0) = f(1) = 1$$

Comment: Is your derivative right?

Comment: I think, your derivatives are incorrect.  $\left(a\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{p}+(1-a)\left(\frac{1-b}{1-a}\right)^{p}\right)'=\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{p}ln(\frac{b}{a})+(1-a)^{1-p}ln{(1-a)}(1-b)^{p}+(1-a)^{1-p}ln{(1-b)}(1-b)^{p}$

Comment: Naturally, i was not in time to write the comment :-)   $\left(a\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{p}+(1-a)\left(\frac{1-b}{1-a}\right)^{p}\right)'=a\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{p}ln(\frac{b}{a})+(1-a)^{1-p}ln{(1-a)}(1-b)^{p}+(1-a)^{1-p}(1-b)^{p}ln{(1-b)}$

Comment: And I missed "-" in front of the second summand... as usual :-)

Comment: I like your approach, but the problem now is to prove that $f'>0$. BTW, why do you need $f''$?

Comment: because f' is negative at 0 and positive at 1

Comment: Therefore f decreases first and then increase in (0,1) so f(0)=f(1)=1 means f is less than 1 between them

Comment: Oh my... Indeed... and I was struggling to prove that f'>0 for all p>0... This should (I hope) put the end my struggles with the core prove I have been facing for about 2 months (and, hopefully, to finish the whole "project"). Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. And I am really sorry for the silly mistakes I made at first, which is quite funny actually haha